# "Stop running this script" Confirmation Box - How can I get more details about the script?

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm looking into turning my AngularJS application to be compatible with IE8 and I'm getting this popup confirmation error:

[image]

Now, I want to get more details about this - like what file & line caused this to invoke.

I've google it and I understand that it  appears in a different occasion based on which browser is running.

I'd like to get **more details about the script that caused this popup to invoke** (specifically in IE8).

Comment: It generally appears when a script has halted the thread for some time, and isn't answering, and that usually happens when you have scripts with errors in them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand why it happens but I'd like to get more details so I can start understanding where my problems are(I have lots of external js files and I cant guess who's killing me).

Comment: On the left side of statusbar there will reveal an error icon. Click on it and get more details

Answer (score 2):

IE8 makes this warning based on the number of statements and not based on the time the scripts are taking to run. This warning in my opinion is inaccurate.

By default threshold limit for the time-out dialog box is 5,000,000 statements.

Microsoft released a patch to correct this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500

Please note that microsoft also indicates that which is the registry entry to increase this to any level if necessary:

- Using a Registry Editor such as `Regedt32.exe`, open this key:

  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Styles

  *Note If the Styles key is not present, create a new key that is called Styles.*
- Create a new DWORD value called "**MaxScriptStatements**" under this key, and set the value to the desired number of script statements.

If you are not sure about which value you need to set this to, you can set it to a DWORD value of 0xFFFFFFFF to avoid the dialog box.

When I faced this same problem with Angular/IE8 what I ended up doing was to reducing the size of the objects and "re-architecting" the app along with applying the patch above. I think this is part of the limitation of supporting IE8. 
Our application was using Kendo, JQuery and Angular and we find out that the error could occur at any 'given' time in any 'given' library part of our re-architecting was using lighter UI-Frameworks as well and more custom specific controls only when it was strictly necessary.

Hope it helps and sorry to hear that you are also supporting IE8 :D

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand why it happens but I'd like to get more details so I can start understanding where my problems are(I have lots of external js files and I cant guess who's killing me).

Comment: Chrome (Canary)is excellent tool to profile the resources used in my js app